# Regex to select text with ONLY one tab in front between two specific strings

Tags: regex, tabs, power-automate-desktop

I'm just getting started with Regex and want to select text that has ONLY one tab in front between two specific strings.

In that case I want to select text that is between `ABC` and `CDE` (**don't select** `ABC` and `CDE`) and has ONLY *one* tab in front of it. So I want to select `Rotterdam`, `Amsterdam`, `China` and `Japan` and **do not select** e.g. `Hello` and `I have two tabs in front of me` because they have *two* tabs.

```
EFGADADA
        Hello
EFGHI
        Oslo
        Australia
EFGHI
ABC
    Rotterdam
    Amsterdam
    China
    Japan
        Hello
        I have two tabs in front of me
CDE
        Oslo
        Australia
```

I already have this which **deselects** everything that has two tabs in front of it:

```
(?<!\t\t(.?)+)[ a-zA-ZäöüÄÖÜßé@.()&-/"“]+
```

I know, this selects also `ABC`, `CDE` and `EFGHI`, which of course, don't have any tabs in front of them but thats fine because between `ABC` and `CDE` is only Text that has tabs in front of it.

Btw. I use the Regex inside *Power Automate Desktop*, if that matters.

Comment: What tool or language are you using? You might get all matches in a capture group like this `^\S+((?:\n\t\S+)+)` https://regex101.com/r/6ov6kf/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird Sorry, I forgot to say that. I'm using Regex inside Microsofts Power Automate Desktop to get specifc text values, if you know that. Your code seems to work in your example but I don't think it will work for my use case. I will edit the example a bit more. Thanks anyway for your interest and help!